# D3 get FPS rate during transition

Tags: d3.js

I have a number of chained D3 transitions. For profiling, I would like to get the average fps rate during these transitions, or perhaps the average DOM changes per second. Is it possible to obtain this?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Frame_rate

Comment: Another option is to look at this, and use the tween function to run a counter to sum the number of steps used in the transition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076394/d3js-transition-step-function